# CMake doesn't move files with install()

Tags: cmake

I have this CMakeLists.txt: (main.c is just a hello world)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.8)
project(Test LANGUAGES C)
add_executables(Test main.c)
install(TARGETS Test DESTINATION bin)
```

Test.exe is just outputted to the source directory and the `bin` directory is never created. I'm expecting the `bin` directory to be created in the same directory as `main.c` and Test.exe to be inside `bin`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you running `make install` or equivalent?  The `install` command specifies actions which happen at install time, not build time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, like Fraser said you have to use `make install`. That technically answers my question but the problem I'm having isn't solved. I'll make another question for it.